# How to remove specific character except for the first one using regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I have a string something like, `asd.asd.asd.234432$$..asd888`. Now I want to get a string like, `.234432888`. So what I want to achieve is to remove every dots except for the first one and remove every non number character.

So far I tried `*string*.replace(/[^\d.]/gi, new String())`. But, it does not work as expected.

Comment: `'asd.asd.asd.234432$$..asd888'.match(/\.\d+/)` is eaiser

Comment: @AndyRay, why would I use match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a global regex match of characters:

- `(?<!\..*)` - find `.` that doesn't have `.` before it at any distance (`.*`) using a lookbehind negative assertion. That would be the first `.` encountered.
- `\d+` - find all numbers
- join the found characters:

```js
const str = 'asd.asd.asd.234432$$..asd888';

console.log(str.match(/(?<!\..*)\.|\d+/g).join(''));
```

Comment: it only working if there is dot right before a number. what if the dot is not right before the number?

Comment: thanks, can you please explain it?

Comment: @AbidHasan changed `\d` to `\d+` - some small optimization to join less

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(?<=\.[^.]*)\.|[^\d.]+` regex and replace it with empty string.

Here `(?<=\.[^.]*)\.` part matches all dots except first dot and `[^\d.]+` matches any non-digit non-dot one or more character.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QJaZLc/1)

JS code demo,

```js
let s = 'asd.asd.asd.234432$$..asd888';
console.log(s, ' --> ', s.replace(/(?<=\.[^.]*)\.|[^\d.]+/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputString = 'asd.asd.asd.234432$$..asd888';

const transformedString = inputString.replace(/(\..*?)\./g, '$1').replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');

console.log(transformedString);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Possible and easier with the `string.match()`:

```js
string.match(/(\.)(?:[^0-8](\d+))*/).join('');
```

Also, there's a thing that you should be aware of: In `[]`, you can't use special statements such as `\d` - `[\d]` is treated as „`\` or `d`“. You need to use character range such as `0-9`.

Answer (score 0):

You can match any character except for a digit or a dot, or you match a dot if it is not the first one in the string.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
[^\d.]+|(?<!^[^.]*)\.
```

**Explanation**

- `[^\d.]+` Match 1 or more times any character except for a digit or `.`
- `|` Or
- `(?<!^[^.]*)\.` Match a `.` asserting that is it not the first one from the start of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RFRbC1/1)

```js
const regex = /[^\d.]+|(?<!^[^.]*)\./g;
const s = "asd.asd.asd.234432$$..asd888";
console.log(s.replace(regex, ''));
```